# How to сancel the execution of the code when you click on the element again (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I have a chunk of code like this:

```
<div class="add_like like__count" data-post-id="167" data-user-id="1">
  <img src="img/icons/liker.svg" alt="liker">
    <span id="like">0</span>
</div>

jQuery('.add_like').on('click',function(e){

        jQuery(this).removeClass('add_like');

        let likeCounter = jQuery('#like').html();
        let num = Number(likeCounter);
        jQuery('#like').html(num+1);
});
```

The idea is that when you click again, the jQuery code does not work again. But it doesn't work. Even after the first click, the class (add_like) is removed. With further clicks, jQuery continues to work.
I am not good at jQuery help to solve this issue. I need this code to work only on the first click. And didn't work anymore until the page was reloaded.

Comment: use one('click') instead of  on('click')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery "**one**" is specially designed to handle one click. which means once per element with the class of **add_like** to make it work a second time you should reload the page.

```
Query('.add_like').one('click',function(e){
    
    //jQuery(this).removeClass('add_like');
    
    let likeCounter = jQuery('#like').html();
    let num = Number(likeCounter);
    jQuery('#like').html(num+1);

});
```